# Shortest distance from a corner to the longest diagonal of a tesseract?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

What is the shortest distance from a corner to the longest diagonal of a tesseract?

Also, is it true that the corners are equidistant from this diagonal?

If not, is there a sort of symmetry that some of the corners have? (I.e. I suspect that not all 14 remaining corners result in a different distance from the diagonal, some would result in the same shortest distance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the $n$-dimensional tesseract where the vertices are the
points with coordinates all of which are $0$ and $1$. Just consider the
diagonal $OP$ where $O$ is the origin and $P$ is the all-one vector.
Consider any point $Q=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. If $R$ is the nearest point on
$OP$ to $Q$ then $QR$ lies within the hyperplane through $Q$ normal to
$OP$, that is $x_1+\cdots+x_n=A$ where $A=a_1+\cdots+a_n$. Therefore
$R=(A/n,\ldots,A/n)$ and
$$|QR|^2=\sum_{j=1}^n(a_j-A/n)^2=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2-\frac{A^2}{n}.$$
In the case where $Q$ is a vertex of the tesseract, it has $r$ coordinates
equal to $1$ and $n-r$ equal to zero. Then $A=r$ and
$$|QR|^2=r-\frac{r^2}n=\frac{r(n-r)}n.$$